# Keyboard failing to print out tilde this character

Tags: keyboard

I use ssh to raspberry pi from windows with putty. Otherwise, I use macbook air to remotely control windows. Preliminarily, in a sooner time, I was able to type tilde this character via combine key(shirf+~). No idea why there is such as this matter suddenly happening. Wish some advice. Thanks.

Comment: The symptom is gone right now. I don't know the cause. I shut down macbook latest night and reboot my macbook this morning. Then, I remotely control my windows with ssh putty.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing your keyboard layout.

Run `sudo raspi-config` from the terminal, go to `Internationalisation Options`, select `Change Keyboard Layout`, then select the applicable setting for your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. I will have been using this possibly in the future.